# Bright pixels appear on my model in material preview with Cycles on Blender 2.82

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I am currently following Blender Guru's donut tutorial for 2.8, but I've had an issue with the material preview in the viewport. This seems to come from the donut, where the entire object simply pixelates with bright and blinding white pixels along with a few other rainbow colors. When moving my view around, the pixels leave a trail too. I don't know if this is an issue with switching from Eevee then to Cycles, or if it is something else. Here is how my issue looks like:

[image]

If I add back the icing and sprinkles:

[image]

When I zoom in and out:

[image]

Edit: Here are my computer specs:

- Name: ALIENWARE13R3
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60 GHz
- RAM: 32 Gb
- System: x64
- OS: Windows 10
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060

Here is the blender file to download on MediaFire:
[Donut Tutorial.blend download](https://www.mediafire.com/file/tg6pxlkftifm33r/Donut_Tutorial.blend/file)

Comment: There seems to be something horribly wrong going on with your graphics pipeline. Could you share your .blend-file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can check if the errors can be reproduced on our hardware and share your system specs with us (OS, hardware, etc.)?

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc Thanks a lot for dedicating your time to this. I added the specs to my question, and shared the link to a mediafire to download the file since the link you shared didn't seem to upload correctly my file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I opened your file on my machine and have to inform you that the glitches only occur on your end.

The doughnut looks just fine in my Viewport:

[image: Viewport]

And renders beautifully (this render was done with only 8 samples in about 7 seconds):

[image: Render]

Since you are using a laptop I suspect the switch between IntelHD-Graphics and your dedicated chip my be the cause of this problem. Since I'm not a Windows user I can only give you limited advice on this issue:

1. Make sure all your hardware drivers are up to date.
2. Start Blender with your GTX enabled (right-click on the application, then choose something like "run with NVIDIA")
3. If that doesn't solve your issues and you're positive that neither your OS nor your hardware are at fault here, try filing a Blender bug-report.

Comment: Thank you so much! I checked if my drivers were up to date, but the problem was still there. But then, I did "run with NVIDIA" for Blender, and the issue was gone!